# php smtp issues on windows server for contact form

Tags: php, email, sendmail, contacts

i am having a problem with a contact form on a website. While clicking on submit, a mail need to be sent to the website owner email address.

i have used several mailing scripts, but none seem to be working fine. However, when using the same scripts on another server, its working just fine.

My best guess is that the problem is due to windows server. I have tested the scripts on linux servers, but i never used windows server before.

```
<?php
//Retrieve form data. 
//GET - user submitted data using AJAX
$name = ($_GET['name']) ? $_GET['name'] : $_POST['name'];
$email = ($_GET['email']) ?$_GET['email'] : $_POST['email'];
$tel = ($_GET['tel']) ?$_GET['tel'] : $_POST['tel'];
$msg = ($_GET['message']) ?$_GET['message'] : $_POST['message'];
$oname = 'website | Contact Us page';


//flag to indicate which method it uses. If POST set it to 1
if ($_POST) $post=1;


    //recipient
    $to = 'sample@example.com';


    //sender
    $from = $oname . ' <' . $email . '>';

    //subject and the html message
    $subject = $csubject;   
    $comment = '
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <table>
        <tr><td>Name: </td><td>' . $name . '</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Tel: </td><td>' . $tel . '</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Email: </td><td>' . $email . '</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Message: </td><td>' . nl2br($msg) . '</td></tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>';

    //send the mail
    $result = sendmail($to, $subject, $comment, $from);


    //if POST was used, display the message straight away
    if ($_POST) {
        if ($result) echo 'Thank you! We have received your message.';
        else echo 'Sorry, unexpected error. Please try again later';

    //else if GET was used, return the boolean value so that 
    //ajax script can react accordingly
    //1 means success, 0 means failed
    } else {
        echo $result;
    }


//Simple mail function with HTML header
function sendmail($to, $subject, $comment, $from) {
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: ' . $from . "\r\n";


    $result = mail($to,$subject,$comment,$headers);

    if ($result) return 1;
    else return 0;

}

?>
```

A little help would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

edited

contactform.htm

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<form name="contactform" method="post" action="send_form_email.php">
<table width="450px">
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="first_name">First Name *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top"">
  <label for="last_name">Last Name *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="last_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="email">Email Address *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="telephone">Telephone Number</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="telephone" maxlength="30" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="comments">Comments *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <textarea  name="comments" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="6"></textarea>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">   <a href="http://www.freecontactform.com/email_form.php">Email Form</a>
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

send_form_email.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
    $email_to = "sample@example.com";
    $email_subject = "test";


    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
        !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
    }

    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required

    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";


// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

ini_set('sendmail_from', 'example@sample.com');

if(mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers) )

echo  "Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.";


else

echo "error";






?>

<!-- include your own success html here -->


<?php


}
?>
```

when testing these piece of code on the server, it didnt work. I received no mail.

but the same scripts works on another server

thank you for helping

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be you have to configure SMTP on your server

You can use the googles free SMTP server 
Pretty easy to setup too.

study about php mailer in this [link](https://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/wiki/PHPMailer?tm=6)

```
<?php

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

//Send mail using gmail
if($send_using_gmail){
    $mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl"; // sets the prefix to the servier
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
    $mail->Port = 465; // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
    $mail->Username = "your-gmail-account@gmail.com"; // GMAIL username
    $mail->Password = "your-gmail-password"; // GMAIL password
}

//Typical mail data
$mail->AddAddress($email, $name);
$mail->SetFrom($email_from, $name_from);
$mail->Subject = "My Subject";
$mail->Body = "Mail contents";

try{
    $mail->Send();
    echo "Success!";
} catch(Exception $e){
    //Something went bad
    echo "Fail :(";
}

?>
```

Comment: i think the smtp server is working fine, since other websites are not having mailing issues. Can u explain if i need to configure it, how to do it?

Comment: other website are in the same server?

Comment: You have to setup the SMTP in your php.ini file have the look at this following page,I hope SMTP is not setup on the server http://roshanbh.com.np/2007/12/sending-e-mail-from-localhost-in-php-in-windows-environment.html

Comment: thank you, but as i said, am having problem regarding the servers. I know the scripts are working, and most probably it would be working on localhost also. But its with this windows server that its not working.

thank you for the help.

Comment: That's only because of setting not done for the SMTP in php.ini(server setting) look into that there's no need to change the code if its working in another server